# Set bottom fixed while scaling in Android

Tags: java, android, android-layout, layout, scaling

I have two Image views, one is below the other one.

I want to resize the images, and when one is getting bigger, I want the other one to be become smaller. But, I also want the image above to be pivoted at the top and the lower one to be pivoted at bottom.

I achieved this on first one (top), but I couldn't make the one below pivot at the bottom.

Question: How can I go about making the **bottom** image pivot and become smaller as the **top** one becomes *larger*.

Here is my layout :

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    android:id="@+id/root">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/imageView"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:scaleType="fitCenter"
            android:src="@drawable/as" />

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/imageView"
            android:scaleType="fitCenter"
            android:id="@+id/imageView2"
            android:src="@drawable/as" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Here is my Java code :

```
 root = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.root);
        iv = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);
        iv2 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView2);
        iv.setPivotY(iv.getX());


   detector = new GestureDetectorCompat(this, new GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onScroll(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float distanceX, float distanceY) {
            iv.setScaleY(iv.getScaleY() - distanceY / root.getHeight());
            iv2.setScaleY(iv2.getScaleY()+ distanceY / root.getHeight());
           return true;
        }
    });
```

Comment: In future, please do not edit your question to include a new problem and invalidate existing answers. Instead, create a new question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not entirely sure what you are trying to achieve, but this code splits the screen into two section, each of which is used for one of the imageviews. I have left the code that scales the images and have code to set the pivot points, assuming you have some purpose in mind. I do suggest you comment them out and try to see if you get the desired results without them.

activity_main.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                tools:context=".MainActivity"
                android:id="@+id/root">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter"
        android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/imageView"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter"
        android:id="@+id/imageView2"

        android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

MainActivity.java:

```
import android.support.v4.view.GestureDetectorCompat;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.GestureDetector;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;

import static com.example.justtesting.R.id.imageView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity{

    GestureDetectorCompat detector;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        final int minH = 10;
        final RelativeLayout root = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.root);
        final ImageView iv = (ImageView) findViewById(imageView);
        final ImageView iv2 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView2);

        detector = new GestureDetectorCompat(this, new GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onScroll(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float distanceX, float distanceY) {
                int height = iv.getHeight() + iv2.getHeight();
                android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams layoutParams = iv.getLayoutParams();
                if ((int) distanceY + layoutParams.height < minH)
                    layoutParams.height = minH;
                else if ((int) distanceY + layoutParams.height > height - minH)
                    layoutParams.height = height-minH;
                else
                    layoutParams.height = (int) distanceY + layoutParams.height;
                android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams layoutParams2 = iv2.getLayoutParams();
                layoutParams2.height = height-layoutParams.height;
                iv.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
                iv2.setLayoutParams(layoutParams2);
                return true;
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        return detector.onTouchEvent(event);
    }
}
```

Notice that I replaced your referenced image with the default launcher image in both ImageViews as I don't have your image file in my project.

```
android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
```

Change it as you see fit.

And here are some screenshots of the app running on Nexus 5 emulator (X86-64)/Android-22 (same result with Android-23).

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Good luck!

Comment: None of your code works correctly, when I swipe up or swipe down, it moves unexpectedly.

Comment: What version of Android are you compiling to and what version of Android are you testing it on? Also, just for completeness, where/how do you uses the detector object? When I test the proposed code, the size of the two images change "expectedly": one gets smaller as the other gets larger. But I might not be understanding the question correctly, or I might be compiling/testing in a different environment than yours.

Comment: SDK version is 23 and I'm trying on Nexus 5 emulator.

Comment: Hmmm, that is exactly what I have been testing. OK, one last attempt. I will edit my post and include the entire java code and xml files (other than project related setup files and the AndroidManifest, they are the only files in my test project.) I am also including a few screen shots of the result.

Comment: hello, this one is working great. Except the widths are also changing, how can I stop widths change? I only want heights to change.

Comment: And top and bottom are moving a little bit when they are resizing.

Answer (score 2):

In your layout xml file, set  `android:pivotY` and `android:pivotX` to 1/2 of the layout dimensions.

Comment: If you can answer that question, you can get 100 bounty.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using `LinearLaout` with `layout_weight`